# Bind multiple actions to one key in lighttable

Tags: key-bindings, lighttable

I'm using the vim plugin in lighttable.
When I'm in insert-mode and press ESC while a code completion window is shown, it closes that window but doesn't exit insert mode.

I'd like lighttable to do both at the same time when pressing ESC because I got so used to it in plain vim.

I've tried to bind ESC to both of those actions:

```
[:app "esc" [
              :auto-complete.remove
              :vim.send-key "esc"
             ]
  ]
```

But this doesn't work. Is this even possible? Is there another workaround for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding the following to your *user.keymap* file:

```
[:editor "esc" :auto-complete.remove (:vim.send-key "<Esc>")]
```

But this isn't currently possible.

I created [an issue](https://github.com/LightTable/Vim/issues/62) for this on GitHub for the LT Vim plugin repo. 'Fixing' this is *relatively* minor change to CodeMirror upstream of LT. I'll update this answer again if any other progress is made.